# Is it appropriate to install a server(eg XAMPP) in order to create a DB with Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to make a new connection with Oracle SQL Developer but an error is ocurred :
"The Network Adapter could not establish the connection ".

Comment: You  need an **Oracle database server** not PHP

Comment: Could you suggest me one ?I have already install "Oracle SQL Developer" @a_horse_with_no_name